# add action fails for value of imagepath

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

In my database I have a `varchar` field to save the path include the name of an imagefile. In my viewscript I also use this field. If I insert for a test a pathname in my database via phpadmin everything works fine.

If I use my Controller addAction I can´t save the path, without error.

Here is my addAction:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Buch();
$form->submit->setLabel('Add');
$this->view->form = $form;
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        $autor = $form->getValue('autor');
        $verlag = $form->getValue('verlag');
        $titel = $form->getValue('titel');
        if( $form->getElement('datei')->receive() <> 1)
        {
            echo '    filename:      '. $form->getElement('datei')->receive();
            $imagepath = $form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
            //echo '    filename:      '. $form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
            $pathparts = pathinfo($form->getElement('datei')->getFileName());
            //echo '    pathparts:     '. $pathparts;
            //then get the part that you want to use
            $originalFilename = $pathparts['basename'];
            //echo '     originalFilename:      '. $originalFilename;
            //echo '     Test basename:      '. $originalFilename['basename'];
            $form->getElement('datei')->addFilter('Rename','images' );      //'/images/upload/',$originalFilename
            //rename funktioniert so nicht
            $originalFilename = $pathparts['basename'];
            $imagepath=$form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
            $imagepath = str_replace($imagepath, "/images/cover/".$originalFilename, $imagepath);   //funktioniert !!!
            //echo '     imagepath:      '. $imagepath;
            $books = new Application_Model_DbTable_Bibliothek();
            $books->addBook( $autor, $titel, $verlag,  $imagepath );
        }
        else{
            $imagepath=NULL;
        }

        //  $this->_helper->redirector('index');
    } else {
        $form->populate($formData);
    }
}
```

Please don´t mind I tried a bit around, so I have some comments left. I tested the variable `$imagepath` and it delivers the wanted value, which is: `/images/cover/imagename.jpg`. Where is the error in this `pathvalue`?

And here is my add Function which I use to store in my database:

```
public function addBook($autor, $titel, $verlag, $pfad)
{
    $data = array(
        'autor' => $autor,
        'titel' => $titel,
        'verlag' => $verlag,
        'pfad' => $pfad,                    
    );
    $this->insert($data);
}
```

It works quite fine, it saves all comming data instead of the `$pfad` variable.

NEW:
must be something with the format of `$imagepath`, I just added for testing: `$imagepath= '/images/cover/Labyrinth_200.jpg';` and find the value in my database table. So the error should be in the format of getting the value of `$imagepath`.

Comment: What's the error-message?

Comment: As I wrote before I do not get any error message just the link is dismissed in the recordset

Answer (score 0):

I just found my (very stupid) error.

I changed the blocks in my control structure like following:

```
            if( $form->getElement('datei')->receive() <> 1)
            {
                $imagepath=NULL;
            }
            else{

            echo '    filename:      '. $form->getElement('datei')->receive();
                $imagepath = $form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
                //echo '    filename:      '. $form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
                $pathparts = pathinfo($form->getElement('datei')->getFileName());
                //echo '    pathparts:     '. $pathparts;
                //then get the part that you want to use
                $originalFilename = $pathparts['basename'];
                //echo '     originalFilename:      '. $originalFilename;
                //echo '     Test basename:      '. $originalFilename['basename'];
                 $form->getElement('datei')->addFilter('Rename','images' );     //'/images/upload/',$originalFilename
                 //rename funktioniert so nicht
                $originalFilename = $pathparts['basename'];
                $imagepath=$form->getElement('datei')->getFileName();
                $imagepath = str_replace($imagepath, "/images/cover/".$originalFilename, $imagepath);   //funktioniert !!!
                //echo '     imagepath:      '. $imagepath;

            }
            //$imagepath= '/images/cover/Labyrinth_200.jpg';
            $books = new Application_Model_DbTable_Bibliothek();

            $books->addBook( $autor, $titel, $verlag, $imagepath );
```

Before that I tried `if( $form->getElement('datei')->receive() = 1)` to validate my condition. But I got an error. So I switched the two blocks and now it works.